# What version of SAGA is supported by QGIS 3.18 on Ubuntu 20.04.2, and how do I install it?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, saga

I have been using QGIS on Windows 10, but now have installed Ubuntu (20.04.2) on a high spec laptop and want to use QGIS on that instead.

I installed QGIS 3.18; SAGA was not installed with it. `sudo apt install SAGA` gave me version 7.3.0 - and a message *SAGA version 7.3.0 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues* when I try to run anything from SAGA. And I did encounter issues, sadly.

I would like to install a version of SAGA which *is* supported - but an hour of searching both here and elsewhere has not brought me the answer. I can't say for sure that's not my fault - maybe I'm missing something obvious - but I can't find it. My Windows 10 QGIS has SAGA 2.3.2, but `sudo apt install saga=2.3.2` just returns *E: Version '2.3.2' for 'saga' was not found*.

I am one of those users of Ubuntu who might be classed in the "A little knowledge is a dangerous thing" category - I've been using it on and off for years, but I probably feel like I know a lot more than I actually do, so maybe there's an obvious solution that I'm missing. But I just want to have QGIS with working SAGA on this machine and I can't find what I need to make that happen.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the source code ([../python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaAlgorithmProvider.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaAlgorithmProvider.py)) on lines 43-44.

```
REQUIRED_VERSION = '2.3.'
BETA_SUPPORT_VERSION = '7.'
```

The officially supported version of SAGA for QGIS 3.18 is 2.3.x.

You could try compiling SAGA 2.3.x from source.